# -webkit-clip-path:inset equivalent in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, clip-path

***Simple question***: I got this `clip-path mask` working with `Chrome` and would like to know a simple way to get the same effect with `Firefox`.

I did some research and saw that `Firefox's` `clip-path` works with `svg`, but is that the only way? How to dynamically change the `mask` in that case?

HTML:

```
 <div id="image1" class="frame">
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
 </div>
 <input id="range1" type="range" value=0 max=100 oninput="UpdateImage('image1');"></input>
```

Javascript:

```
function UpdateImage(id) {
    image_elem = document.getElementById(id);
    layers = image_elem.getElementsByClassName("layer");
    range = document.getElementById("range1");
    layers[1].setAttribute("style", "-webkit-clip-path:inset(" + range.value + "% 0 0 0)");
}
```

[Here's it working with Chrome.](https://jsfiddle.net/6wdvz9jo/)

Comment: P.s. you can use the same image for the second one but applying filter: grayscale(100%); saves bandwith. (http://demosthenes.info/blog/532/Convert-Images-To-Black-And-White-With-CSS)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! In this case the image just happened to be a grayscale mirror, but it is not intended for all of them to be like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your concern is browser support, I would suggest a different approach for the same output : using height rather than `clip-path`.

This will provide browser support for (at least) chrome, Firefox, IE, safari, opera... :

```js
function UpdateImage(id) {
    image_elem = document.getElementById(id);
    layers = image_elem.getElementsByClassName("layer");
    range = 100 - document.getElementById("range1").value;
    layers[1].setAttribute("style", "height:" + range + "%");
}
```

```css
.frame {
    position:relative;
    width: 375px;
    height: 250px;
}
.frame .layer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: left bottom;
}
#image1 .layer:nth-child(1) {
    background-image:url("http://rlc.site90.net/images/img1_layer0.jpg");
}
#image1 .layer:nth-child(2) {
    background-image:url("http://rlc.site90.net/images/img1_layer1.jpg");
}
#range1 {
    width:375px;
}
```

```html
<div id="image1" class="frame">
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
</div>
<input id="range1" type="range" value=0 max=100 oninput="UpdateImage('image1');"/>
```

Comment: I marked as accepted because this solution meets my needs. Although, the title might be a bit misleading now that is has nothing to do with clip-paths.
Also, to have the exact same effect I had to change the function to `(1 - range)` for it to clip in the same direction.